# .htaccess config not correctly working

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Here is my current situation:

https://i.gyazo.com/36e69109e828339b2ec18f8bbc523696.png

As it says on the file

- my url’s look like: http: //localhost/post.php?id=article-slug-name
- How i want them to look like http ://localhost/post/article-slug-name

I've been trying for days and searched all forums, just can't make it work... The file works because the enable-404-page command i include at the end works. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an apache web server you should check whether you have enabled mod_rewrite in your configurations. This often causes trouble.

EDIT:
Since the above wasn't the problem, try changing your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([a-z0-9-]*)$ post.php?id=$1
```

(Note that this does not match anything with upper-case)

What you tried didn't do what you wanted. The first expression is what is searched after in the URL that is provided, so the form you wish for the user to see. So it did the reverse of what you wanted.

If this doesn't work check your conditions.

Little tip for the future: I found that the rules are easily tested here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: I do have it enabled.

Comment: I added a rule-improvement

Comment: You are awesome! I think i get it now, the code works. 

However, for some reason the page when going from the new links do not load my custom style sheet. In the inspector: Style sheet could not be loaded. http://localhost/post/css/style.css. I can't understand why it is loading that link... my html points to 
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Yes. All links pointing to anything in `localhost/post/...` are redirected to `localhost/post.php?id=...`, so it's trying to find the css at `localhost/post.php?id=css/style.css` which obviously doesn't work. Check your conditions. Also check whether REQUEST_FILENAME works as expected, since sometimes it creates problems too. Try putting DOCUMENT_ROOT in front of it too, if nothing else works: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f` and variations